# How to make horizontal menu

Tags: javascript, css

How to make horizontal menu like this: http://www.csd.toshiba.com/cgi-bin/tais/support/jsp/home.jsp (click on downloads) 
So I mean there are 3 listboxes, but I would like to achieve the same effect with nested ul. 
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use `float: left` styles to make things line up horizontally. That's the gist of it. If you want a specific answer you need a specific question... with some code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variety of techniques: http://phrogz.net/JS/ul2menu/purecss_testsuite.html